# Sort data row in sql

Tags: sql, sorting

please help me i have columns from more than one table and the data type for all these columns is integer

i want to sort the data row (not columns (not order by)) Except the primary key column

for example

```
column1(pk)   column2         column3         column4          column5
1             6               5               3                1
2             10              2               3                1
3             1               2               4                3
```

How do I get this result

```
column1(pk)   column2         column3         column4          column5
1             1               3               5                6
2             1               2               3                10
3             1               2               3                4
```

Please help me quickly .. Is it possible ?? or impossible ??? 
if impossible how I could have a similar result regardless of sort

Comment: Please don't hurry the people you ask for help.

Comment: This STRONGLY indicates a database design issue.  Your fields should mean something.  Being able to rearrange them numerically means they all represent the same kind of data, which means they should probably be in a normalized table.

Answer (score 1):

What database are you using?  The capabilities of the database are important.  Second, this suggests a data structure issue.  Things that need to be sorted would normally be separate entities . . . that is, separate rows in a table.  The rest of this post answers the question.

If the database supports pivot/unpivot you can do the following:

(1) Unpivot the data to get in the format , , 
(2) Use row_number() to assign a new column, based on the ordering of the values.
(3) Use the row_number() to create a varchar new column name.
(4) Pivot the data again using the new column.

You can do something similar if this functionality is not available.

First, change the data to rows:

```
(select id, 'col1', col1 as val from t) union all
(select id, 'col2', col2 from t) union all
. . .
```

Call this byrow.  The following query appends a row number:

```
select br.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by val) as seqnum
from byrow br
```

Put this into a subquery to unpivot.  The final solution looks like:

```
with byrow as (<the big union all query>)
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then val end) as col1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then val end) as col2,
       ...
from (select br.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by val) as seqnum
      from byrow br
     ) br
group by id
```

Comment: It is called normalisation. But you could view it as EAV-modelling, too.

Comment: database in sql 2008 .. i use asp.net2010 language .. the function not clear .. I Beginner

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot function of sql server to convert the row in column. Apply the sorting there and again convert column to row using unpivot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example using PIVOT, you should be able to adapt this to meet your needs

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx

Comment: ok i understand the example .. But it does not explain to me what I want .. (pivot) is ready function ?? or what ?